# How much csv parsing can/should be processed in the front-end?

Tags: html, json, rest, csv, file-upload

I am about to:

- create a web interface where the user can type in email addresses, which are then sent up to the server in one json bulk, which is then used for messaging these users.
- I also have the requirement to be able to upload a csv file with a long list of email addresses. The problem is that the number of email addresses can be very large. We're talking about in the thousands or even more.

Theoretically I can either parse the csv file in the front-end and send the email addresses up in a json object (as I already have the api for the first use case where the email addresses are typed in and sent as a json), or I could upload these csv files to our db and do their parsing on the server side.

- Should consider processing the csv files in the front-end at all?
- What should be a **"safe" number of items for processing in the front-end** without breaking anything, or ending up with a heavily compromised user experience?

Can anyone comment from experience? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What should be a "safe" number of items for processing in the
>   front-end without breaking something, or ending up with a heavily
>   compromised user experience?

This depends on the user's machine. 
No one here would be able to give you a definitive answer on your question.

---

Anyway, you can use the *[Web Workers API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers)*

*Web Workers* allow you to create long running ***asynchronous*** threads in the background without heavily affecting/freezing your UI. You can show a spinner indicating that the CSV is being processed. Meanwhile your users would be able to interact with the UI just fine.

That's your best bet where [supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=webworkers).

---

> Should consider processing the csv files in the front-end at all?

String parsing is *usually* a process that is optimised by modern browsers in some cases. If you move the computation to the server you need to scale your server to meet demands for the calculations as more and more users use your web-app.

You could get playful with it and detect the processing capabilities of the user's machine - if capable, use Web Workers, if not use the server to do this.

The most comprehensive way to do this is by defining a [Browser Test Matrix](http://www.teknologika.com/blog/browser-compatibility-testing/) and test for yourself. 
You can even emulate bandwidths you want to target/test, specifically, using [Network Throttling in Chrome Dev Tools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/device-mode#network-conditions)